# What is the difference between timezone.now and db.models.functions.Now?

Tags: django, django-models, django-timezone

Can anyone explain the difference between '[django.db.models.functions.Now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#now)' and '[django.utils.timezone.now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now)'?

For example, am I correct that `functions.Now()` returns the system time without timezone stamp, and `timezone.now()` would return UTC timestamp?

When I use `print(timezone.now())` I get the expected timestamp however when I `print(functions.Now())` I get a blank string. Why is this?

In what circumstances is it appropriate to use one method over the other?

Comment: Maybe 'django.db.models.functions.Now' is for filter options only.

Comment: Is it timezone aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`timezone.now(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) returns a `datetime` object with the timezone, given the [**`USE_TZ`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std-setting-USE_TZ) is used.

[**`Now`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#now) on the other hand, is a *database expression*. Indeed, it does *not* determine a `datetime`. It will use `NOW()` at the database side where you query. It will thus work with the clock of the database. If the database thus runs on the same server, it is the server time, whereas if it runs on a different server, it can be a few seconds/minutes earlier/later if the clocks of the two systems are not completely in sync.

If you thus query with:

```
from django.utils import timezone

Post.objects.filter(published_at__lte=timezone.now())
```

Then it will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
WHERE published_at <= 2022-07-27 15:40:00  -- time from Django/Python
```

whereas if we use:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Now

Post.objects.filter(published_at__lte=Now())
```

it will query with:

```
SELECT post.*
FROM post
WHERE published_at <= NOW()  -- databae timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I am using timezone aware fields in django I am best to use `timezone.now()` to compare dates?

Comment: @alias51: normally `NOW()` is the timestamp of the database. On a reasonable server, that should be (close) to the real time. Usually the main advantage is that you can use a `queryset = Post.objects.filter(published_at__lte=Now())` to obtain all posts that are published for example in a `ListView`, whereas for `timezone.now()` you will need to work with `get_queryset`, since you each time have to fetch the current datetime: using it at `queryset = ...` would mean that you always take the `datetime` at the moment that file was interpreted for the first time.